# How to learn whether an error occured during a jQuery.ajax() call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-error

I am trying to build a robust

```
$.ajax()
```

call in jQuery, but I am having trouble to understand how to notice whether a call failed.

I understand how to implement *done()* and *fail()* callbacks, and they work quite nicely if the call actually returned anything. But it seems to me that the registered functions are only called if the call itself did not end in a HTTP errors such as 404 or 502. [See this jsFiddle for an example of what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/R4aXg/4/)

So what idiom should I use to catch possible HTTP errors and act accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. In process of editing your fiddle.

```
 $.ajax({
     statusCode: {
         404: function() {
             alert("page not found");
         }
     }
 });
```

**EDIT**: I tweaked your `.fail()` function to handle multiple response status codes collectively (I think this should serve what you were looking for). [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JLDVQ/1/)

```
.fail(function (response) {
    if ($.inArray(response.status, [404, 302, 502]) != -1) {
        $('pre').append("My callback fired, ");
    } else {
        $('pre').append("oops, error? ");
    }
})
```

Comment: bummer! what was I trying.. Cross browser AJAX call not supported.. Have to find another way to test this..

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the not-same-origin trouble, this stuff haunts me in my dreams. Although I do not understand why it has been a problem here, I thought asking for JSONP is the way to avoid the same origins policy!? Also, it is a little bit disappointing that one has to register an individual callback for every error code. After all, there are quite a few different error codes...

Comment: no, it was me who commented the `jsonp` code and started trying AJAX calls and got myself stuck into this trouble. So, my bad. And the `statusCode` method works fine even while using `jsonp` callbacks, I have tested it for cross-domain calls too.

Comment: @MRA I have edited my answer to something that resembles to what you were looking for, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Along with @face's answer, you may want to switch to `$.getJSON`. I tested it and all the callbacks were working correctly. I think it has to do with JSONP.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but isn't $.getJSON just an alias for an $.ajax call? At a first glance, I really don't understand the advantage of using $.getJSON.

Comment: It looks like it from the source to, but if you look at this fidddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R4aXg/5/, things are definitely happening.